# Find mean of the grouped rows of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, rows, mean

I am at very basic level of python. here i am stuck with a problem, can someone help me out?
i have a large pandas dataframe, i want to find rows and do mean, if the first column of each row has some similar value (ex: someinteger seperated by '_' another integer).

i tried to use .split to match 1st number of list, it works for single row but if i have iterate over row, it throws error.
my data frame looks like:

```
d = {'ID' : pd.Series(['1_1', '2_1', '1_2', '2_2' ], index=['0','1','2', '3']),
     'one' : pd.Series([2.5, 2, 3.5, 2.5], index=['0','1', '2', '3']),
     'two' : pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], index=['0', '1', '2', '3'])}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

requirement:

mean of the rows which has similar ID at first position after split. ex. mean of 1_1 and 1_2, 2_1 and 2_2

output:

```
 ID  one  two
0  1  3    2
1  2  2.25 3
```

here is my code,
working version : `((df2.ix[0,0]).split('_'))[0]`

error version:

```
 for i in df2.iterrows():
                   df2[df2.columns[((df2.ix[0,0]).split('_'))[0] == ((df2.ix[0,0]).split('_'))[0]]]
```

looking forward for sooner reply..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you post raw input data, code to reproduce your df and what your desired output df looks like to avoid any ambiguities

Comment: Into your question not as a comment as formatting is lost in comments

Comment: Can you post what the desired output df looks like, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create new column only with first number of your ID column with [`str` methods`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings) and then use`groupby` method:

```
df['groupedID'] = df.ID.str.split('_').str.get(0)

In [347]: df
Out[347]:
     ID  one  two groupedID
0  10_1  2.5    1        10
1   2_1  2.0    2         2
2  10_2  3.5    3        10
3   2_2  2.5    4         2

df1 = df.groupby('groupedID').mean()

In [349]: df1
Out[349]:
            one  two
groupedID
10         3.00    2
2          2.25    3
```

If you need to change name of the index back to 'ID':

```
df1.index.name = 'ID'

In [351]: df1
Out[351]:
     one  two
ID
10   3.00    2
2   2.25    3
```

Comment: hi its fine for this, but what if ID contains 143_1 and i need 143 as ID?